# Dynamically increasing lower bound in CP-SAT from Google's OR tools

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, operations-research, cp-sat

I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically increasing the lower-bound of a variable in the `on_solution_callback(self)` method?

This was just one approach I'd thought of.

I have an array of variables:

```
vars = [model.NewIntVar(0, suitableUpperBound, f'x{i}') for i in range(some_number)]
```

The problem is, once I've found a solution (with the constraints I have in place) for a specific array configuration (say, [0,1,4,5] is a solution), I do *not* want the algorithm to search for solution with the same vars[-1] elemenent (i.e, the same last element). I'd like for it to increment to '6' and search for solutions.

The one approach I thought of was dynamically changing the lower bound each time a solution is found (so it begins the search from another position), but is there a more rigorous, mathematical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Once solve is started. The model is read-only.

Solution callbacks do not allow modifying the model.

You can patch the model to change the bounds of the variable. There are some slight hints on how to do that [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/model.md#introduction).